# Can MATLAB plot a constrained symbolic function?

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

I'm trying to plot the following:

```
syms f_ih n
bi = (1-f_ih)/2
```

where `f_ih` is constrained by: `0 ≤ f_ih ≤ (n-1)/n`. I'd like to show `bi` as a surface plot with independent variables `n` and `f_ih`, but `ezsurf` doesn't allow for variable bounds. How can I do this?

The command I'd love to run would simply be `ezsurf(bi,[0,(n-1)/n])`, but it's not that simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason for requiring the domain to be numeric as opposed to symbolic: the function has to be evaluated in order to obtain actual numbers that can be plotted. It makes no sense to plot something that is purely symbolic like your equations (in Matlab or on paper) unless you specify `n`. Some functions may be scale invariant (not quite the right term mathematically), meaning they look the same when evaluated/plotted on different domains, but Matlab has no way of knowing. Choose a value of `n` that results in a plot that looks how want. Then, if you like, you can remove the numbers from the axes afterwards and label them as if it were for arbitrary `n` even though it's not.

Comment: n would be [1 inf] in this case. I tried plotting this numerically as well, but I again ran into issues with specifying variable bounds.